# Disable Lan wired- arch linux

Tags: networking, laptop, arch-linux

I want to disable the  Network interface: enp8s0 (r8169). I dont it to work not know and not after reboot.
this takes me battery life..and I dont use wired Network at all.
how can I disable it on arch linux?

I tried ip link set enp8s0 down. it worked but when I resume from suspend its comeback

I want also disable this   Integrated Camera (Vimicro corp.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the driver as you did. But for saving battery life its negligible. If youre not using it
its not using much electricity at all. And disabling the ethernet entirely is not recommended because
it just might save you someday. Its not using electricity so thats not a good reason in my view.

Its really the same with the camera. You can disable it to save electricity but if youre not using it it really isnt using electricity. Run top or htop and see what is. There is also a tool in the AUR
called powerstat-git. Most electricity by far gets used in the cpu. So here is where you want to be frugal. Also use a lighter weight DE.